# Failed to break down the props in a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, and here on the site. I have a problem that I do not understand.
I want to disassemble my props so that I will be more comfortable working with it, this is the first time I am doing this for a function component. I always use a class component.

This is the code I wrote down, I have props I get, I printed it and it exists. I want to unpack the props, instead of listing props.classes.root each time, I want to list only classes.root.

This is what I did but it does not work for me, I am trying to register classes.root - I get an error that it is not set, but props.classes.root works fine. I can not understand why

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListItemAvatar from '@material-ui/core/ListItemAvatar';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';

//Redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const styles = (theme) => ({
  ...theme.spreadThis
});

function PreferenceList(props) {
  const {
    user: {
      classes
    }
  } = props;
  console.log(props.classes);

  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState([1]);

  const handleToggle = (value) => () => {
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

    setChecked(newChecked);
  };

  return (
    <List dense className={classes.root}>
      {[0, 1, 2, 3].map((value) => {
        const labelId = `checkbox-list-secondary-label-${value}`;
        return (
          <ListItem key={value} button>
            <ListItemAvatar>
              <Avatar
                alt={`Avatar n°${value + 1}`}
                src={`/static/images/avatar/${value + 1}.jpg`}
              />
            </ListItemAvatar>
            <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={`Line item ${value + 1}`} />
            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
              <Checkbox
                edge="end"
                onChange={handleToggle(value)}
                checked={checked.indexOf(value) !== -1}
                inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
              />
            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
          </ListItem>
        );
      })}
    </List>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(PreferenceList));
```

Comment: Use `useSelector` for accessing redux state and `useDispatch` for dispatching action for functional components

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
   //Object destructuring
   const { classes } = props;
```

Then you can do, `classes.root`, given that you mentioned, `props.classes.root` works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said this is wrong line

```
  const {
    user: {
      classes
    }
  } = props;
```

it should be

```
  const {
      classes
  } = props;
```

Not sure from where you got that user part?

Btw, this method is called destructuring.